# How to go back to the root element in XML using C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to XML Programming using C# and have been trying to grasp the concepts. I have a 2books.xml file which looks like

```
<!--sample XML fragment-->
<bookstore>
  <book genre='novel' ISBN='10-861003-324'>
    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>
    <price>19.95</price>
  </book>
  <book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861001-57-5'>
    <title>Pride And Prejudice</title>
    <price>24.95</price>
  </book>
  <book genre='novel' ISBN='1-861991-57-9'>
    <title>The Honor</title>
    <price>20.12</price>
  </book>
</bookstore>
```

Now using XmlReader when I try this following section of code

```
 using (XmlReader xReader = XmlReader.Create(@"C:\Users\Chiranjib\Desktop\2books.xml"))
            {
                xReader.MoveToContent();
                Console.WriteLine("-----------> Now "+xReader.Name);
                Console.WriteLine("------Inner XML -----> "+xReader.ReadInnerXml()); //Positions the reader to the next root element type after the call
                Console.WriteLine("------OuterXML XML -----> " + xReader.ReadOuterXml()); //Positions the reader to the next root element type after the call -- for a leaf node it reacts the same way as Read()

                while (xReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("In Loop");
                    if ((xReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element) && (xReader.Name == "book"))
                    {
                        xReader.ReadToFollowing("price");
                        Console.WriteLine("---------- In Loop -------- Price "+xReader.GetAttribute("price"));
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
            }
```

obviously xReader.ReadInnerXml() places the reader after call at the End of File and as a result of that xReader.ReadOuterXml() prints nothing.

Now I want xReader.ReadOuterXml() to be called successfully . How can I get back to my previous root node ?
I tried xReader.MoveToElement() but I guess it does not do so .

Comment: you can use the Xml to Linq ( this is very powerful and will help you ) instead of using this way.

Comment: @HakamFostok .. that is using XmlDocument right ? How to achieve this using XmlDocument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do that, as it's not what `XmlReader` was designed for.  What you probably want is a much higher level API like LINQ to XML.

For example, you could loop through your books like this:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

foreach (var book in doc.Descendants("book"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}", (string) book.Element("title"));
    Console.WriteLine("ISBN: {0}", (string) book.Attribute("ISBN"));
    Console.WriteLine("Price: {0}", (decimal) book.Element("price"));
    Console.WriteLine("---");
}
```

See a working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/m99eCl

Comment: Once in the childnodes .. in this API is this possible to go back to the root node ? Could you please tell me how ? Like once the <book> could I get back to <bookstore> ?

Comment: You can do whatever you like, there's no 'cursor' concept as in `XmlReader`.  `doc.Root` will always give you the root node, or you can execute queries from any element using the `Elements`, `Descendants` or `Ancestors` methods.  Google will find you the docs and some more examples.  What do you actually want to do?

Comment: It was just out of curiosity. Thanks for the prompt help Sir . I would love to explore the API.